# How to check if table is already, exists using AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I'm provisioning resources using aws cdk.
Before provisioning dynamodb table (with the name of 'cars') I want to check that there is no such table (see the code example).

How can I do that?

```
import { RemovalPolicy } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { AttributeType, BillingMode, StreamViewType, Table} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";
import { Construct } from "constructs";

export class MyTables extends Construct {
  public readonly cars: Table;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    // if dynamo table with the name 'cars' is not exist <----- How can I check this?
    this.cars = this.createTable('cars'); // this is my own function that creates a table with the name 'cars'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are using CDK in the wrong manner. You should not have to know if a resource already exists while creating it.

For example lets say you have a car dealership application and you wish to manage its resources using IaC, in this case CDK. You would ensure that the CDK stack is responsible for all of the applications resources and not only a sub component.

You can use nested stacks to manage small portions of the application in isolation and you can also import existing resources to a stack.

I don't believe you should be in a situation where you need to conditionally check if a resource exists.

With that said, if your use-case requires it I believe you would need to use a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html) where you use a Lambda to create the table, as it will then have the ability to call `DescribeTable` to understand if it exists beforehand.

Comment: it's a good point. To be fair I'm doing it to speed up the devops process and not to structure my code. 

So, I'm deploying my stack and sometimes get logic errors. Now I need to deploy the code again.

But before deploying the code again I need to destroy it because the table already exists. I just wanted to skip the `cdk destroy` before the `cdk deploy`. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If you do not want to destroy your DynamoDB table and set deletion policy to RETAIN, then you can import that existing resource into the new stack. However, if your table contains no data or data that's not needed, it's usually just more simple to destroy it.

Comment: My removal policy is already set as `destroy`.
But when I do `cdk deploy` I get an error message that the table with the current table name is already existed.

Comment: The you should check why your table was not destroyed during the `cdk destroy` from the underlying CFN events tab in the web-console. Also check the stack drift. If the table does not belong to any stack, then its safe to delete manually.